# Problema al actualizar variable global en BASH

Tags: bash

Estoy realizando un script en bash que se encarga de gestionar ciertos eventos de un punto de acceso utilizando `hostapd`. El problema radica en que mi variable `connected_devices` siempre se queda en 0 y a pesar de que si se genera el evento de `check_device_connection` jamás incrementa el valor, el código es el siguiente.

```
#!/bin/bash

ip_client=192.168.1.71
port=3888
connected_devices=0;

# Función para verificar si un dispositivo está conectado al hostapd
function check_device_connection() {
    # Ejecutar el comando y contar las líneas
    connected_devices_actual=$(hostapd_cli -i wlan0mon list_sta | wc -l)

    # Comparar con el valor anterior
    if [ $connected_devices_actual -gt $connected_devices ]; then
        ((connected_devices++))
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "0"
    fi
}

# Función para verificar si un dispositivo se ha desconectado al hostapd
function check_device_disconnection() {
    # Ejecutar el comando y contar las líneas
    connected_devices_actual=$(hostapd_cli -i wlan0mon list_sta | wc -l)

    # Comparar con el valor anterior
    if [ $connected_devices_actual -lt $connected_devices ]; then
        ((connected_devices--))
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "0"
    fi
}

# Función para verificar si wlan0mon está desconectado
function check_wlan0mon_status() {
    if ! iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep -q "wlan0mon" ; then
        echo "0"
    else
        echo "1"
    fi
}

# Función para verificar si el servidor SSH está respondiendo
function check_ssh_status() {
    if ! pgrep -x "sshd" >/dev/null; then
        echo "0"
    else
        echo "1"
    fi
}

# Función para verificar si el servicio hostapd está en ejecución
function check_hostapd_status() {
    if ! pgrep -x "hostapd" >/dev/null; then
        echo "0"
    else
        echo "1"
    fi
}

# Función principal para monitorear eventos y enviar mensajes al socket del cliente Java
function monitor_events() {
    while true; do
        if [ "$(check_device_connection connected_devices)" -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "DEVICE_CONNECTED" | nc "$ip_client" "$port"
        fi

        if [ "$(check_device_disconnection connected_devices)" -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "DEVICE_DISCONNECTED" | nc "$ip_client" "$port"
        fi

        if [ "$(check_wlan0mon_status)" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "WLAN0MON_DISCONNECTED" | nc "$ip_client" "$port"
        fi

        if  [ "$(check_ssh_status)" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "SSH_NOT_RESPONDING" | nc "$ip_client" "$port"
        fi

        if [ "$(check_hostapd_status)" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "HOSTAPD_STOPPED" | nc "$ip_client" "$port"
        fi
        
    echo $connected_devices #En este punto trato de imprimir el valor actualizado y siempre da 0
    sleep 2  # Esperar 2 segundos antes de verificar nuevamente
    done
}

monitor_events
```

En consola siempre recibo varios 0 a pesar de que si se está conectando el dispositivo al hostapd correctamente, de hecho, he comprobado el comando `hostapd_cli -i wlan0mon list_sta | wc -l` y si da el valor correcto después de que se conecta un dispositivo, ¿alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la variable `connected_devices` se la está pasando el proceso padre a los procesos hijos (tanto la subshell del `while` como la subshell en la que se ejecuta la función) con 0, y por más que los hijos la modifiquen dentro de su scope, no van a poder interferir con el valor de la variable del proceso padre.

Por eso siempre te va a dar 0, porque nunca está siendo modificada la variable del proceso padre.

Una solución que encuentro es la de parametrizar correctamente, y en lugar de modificar la variable global, mejor modificar una local pasada como parametro.

Aquí un bosquejo:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

connected_devices=0

check_device_connection() {
    local -i _connected_devices=$1
    connected_devices_actual=4

    if [ $connected_devices_actual -gt ${_connected_devices} ]; then
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "0"
    fi
}

monitor_events() {
    while true; do

        if [ "$(check_device_connection connected_devices)" -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "DEVICE_CONNECTED"
            ((connected_devices++))
        fi
        
        echo $connected_devices 
        sleep 2  
    done
}

monitor_events
```

Otra opción es la de crear un archivo temporal con el contenido de esos cambios de la variable, y leerlos desde ahi. De esa manera, tanto los procesos padres como los subprocesos pueden interactuar con ese valor

Aquí un bosquejo:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

connected_devices=0
echo -n connected_devices > /tmp/connected_devices.log

check_device_connection() {
    local -i _connected_devices=$(cat /tmp/connected_devices.log)
    connected_devices_actual=4

    if [ $connected_devices_actual -gt ${_connected_devices} ]; then
        ((_connected_devices++))
        echo -n "$_connected_devices" > /tmp/connected_devices.log
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "0"
    fi
}

monitor_events() {
    while true; do

        if [ "$(check_device_connection)" -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "DEVICE_CONNECTED"
        fi
        
        _connected_devices=$(cat /tmp/connected_devices.log)
        echo $_connected_devices 
        sleep 2  
    done
}

monitor_events
```

Esta segunda opción tiene los problemas de que no es portable, requiere permisos de escritura, y hace las cosas un tanto más "confusas".

Otro problema que tiene tu código es que una función hace dos cosas, y entre ellas modifica una variable global, lo cual es mala practica porque permite problemas como los que acabas de tener.

Osea, la funcion `check_device_connection` debería revisar la conexión del dispositivo y SOLO ESO (pero estás obligando a esa función a que también incremente una variable externa a ella). Ya con el resultado almacenado en una variable, debería ser suficiente para iniciar otro proceso con base en él.